# Django-postman - History in reply

Tags: python, django, django-apps

I am using Django-postman version 3.1.0. When users are replying to received messages all of the previous message history is automatically entered into the reply text area. I would like to know if it is possible to disable this behaviour.

My settings file for Postman is as follows:

```
POSTMAN_DISALLOW_ANONYMOUS = True
POSTMAN_DISABLE_USER_EMAILING = True
POSTMAN_AUTO_MODERATE_AS = True
POSTMAN_DISALLOW_COPIES_ON_REPLY = False
POSTMAN_AUTOCOMPLETER_APP = {
    'arg_default': 'postman_users',
}
```

Example of data automatically entered into the reply text area.

```
> Reply Email One
> Example
>> Reply Email Two
>> Example 
>>> Reply Email Three
>>> Example
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pull request has been accept that resolves this as an issue..